# localizar palavra dentro de strings array

Tags: php, array

estou usando o seguinte código:

```
foreach ($lista_grupos as $key => $value) {
    if(strpos($lista_grupos[$key],'Tecnologia_da_Informacao')===true){
        $admin = true;
    }else{
        $admin = false;
    }
}
```

Porém sempre retorna false, não encontra a string que desejo. O que estou fazendo de errado?
Segue array:

```
(array =>
    [21] => CN=Tecnologia_da_Informacao,OU=Tecnologia_da_Informacao,OU=03-Operadora,DC=asdt,DC=com,DC=br
    [22] => CN=asdasd,OU=02-Grupos,DC=uniiaca,DC=com,DC=br
    [23] => CN=asdasd,OU=02-Grupos,DC=jçasdia,DC=com,DC=br
)
```

Comment: Isso ai tem cara de ldap.

Comment: É sim, mas não descobri como conseguir exatamente o nome do grupoo, desta forma está trazendo os grupos que a pessoa participa em um array

Comment: Você precisa sair do loop quando encontrar o que procura, senão pode mudar sua variável para false na passada seguinte.

Comment: fiz o teste, mas não entra no if verdadeiro.

Comment: `if(strpos($value, 'Tecnologia_da_Informacao')  !== false)`

Comment: Não compreendi, por que diferente de false?

Comment: Cara, dá um tapa nesse código php aí

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faz muito tempo que não programo em php mas pelo que li na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php), o `strpos()` retorna um inteiro e você compara com boolean ali. Pela documentação, utilize algo assim:

```
if ($pos !== false) {
    $admin = true;
    return ...;
}
```

O `===` compara o resultado mais o tipo. O `strpos()` pode retornar false mas nunca vai retornar true e sim um inteiro da primeira ocorrência da sua string ([Operadores PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php)).